# Custom control not keeping viewstate of items inside panel

Tags: .net, vb.net, custom-controls

So I am using Bootstrap and created a custom VB.net control that creates the modal and shows it.  My body and my footer of the modal are made from the `Panel` control.  On the front end inside the body of the modal I have added a `CheckBoxList` control and I am binding to it.  So when I click a button the `CheckBoxList` loses it's items.  I need to be able to see which items were selected.

on the backend.

```
<Bindable(True), Category("Appearance"), DefaultValue(""), Description("Modal Body."), _  
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),   PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)> _  
Public Overridable Property ModalBody As Panel  
    Get  
        Return _ModalBody  
    End Get  
    Set(value As Panel)  
        _ModalBody = New Panel  
        _ModalBody = value  
        _ModalBody.CssClass = "modal-body"  
    End Set  
End Property
```

on the front end.

```
<ModalBody runat="server">  
  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkBoxTest" runat="server"></asp:CheckBoxList>
</ModalBody>`
```

I don't know how to make it keep the viewstate.  I've done research, just haven't found a solution.